# Switch environment files in vue with docker compose

Tags: docker, vue.js, docker-compose, environment-variables

I want to either pass Vue environment variables to my Vue client with docker compose or tell my client to use a diffenret .env file.

The problem is i cannot access the VUE_APP_ROOT_URL variable nor can I switch between the .env files.

```
 services:
      client_test:
        build: ./papasmuenzenfrontend/.
        container_name: vue_test
        restart: always
        environment:
          - NODE_ENV:test
          - VUE_APP_ROOT_URL=localhost:50598
        ports:
          - '8081:8080'
```

Dockerfile

FROM node:lts-alpine

```
RUN npm install -g http-server
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "http-server", "dist" ]
```

[image: env files]

Comment: Can not happen as env is controlled in Vue App not the container. You can do environment handling by container in nodejs but not vue-cli app.

Comment: I answered my question. It worked with a custom variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out how to do it:

In my package.json I have the following configuration

> ```
> "test_build": "vue-cli-service build --mode test",
> "production": "vue-cli-service build --mode production",
> "development": "vue-cli-service build --mode development"
> ```

docker-compose file:

```
  client_test:
      args:
        - myenv=development
```

docker file:

```
ARG myenv RUN npm run $myenv
```

When building the project the $myenv gets passed to the build in the package.json where it then switches to the different environment files.